# AWS EC2 PHP : Unable to set the session value, but session id is generating

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, session, amazon-ec2

I have hosted my code igniter application in AWS EC2. In that session is not setting the values in my login process. In php.ini file, i have set the session save path to `/tmp`.

```
session.save_path = '/tmp'
```

Session started and session id is generating. But session values are not storing.I have printed the `$_SESSION` and session id, below is the output.

```
string(26) "038vbmtjecvkqft02ou813qvo1" array(1) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1540479344) }
```

I have my session code as follows,

```
$this->session->set_userdata('frontusername', $res->Email);
$this->session->set_userdata('frontname', $res->FirstName);
$this->session->set_userdata('frontuserid', $res->Id);
```

Its working fine in my another server, but not here in AWS EC2.
Have restared the apache after setting the save path and checked the error log under /var/log. No error. 
Also /tmp folder is writable.

My php.ini file, [image]

Searching for last two days, no luck. Any help please, thanks in advance.

Comment: How did `$_SESSION` print values then?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Can you show us the source code of the class you're using for session handling in `$this->session`?

Comment: @vivek_23, yes, $_SESSION prints only __ci_last_regenerate, not my values

Comment: i am using php 7 in ec2 and php 5 in my another server. anything related to this?

Comment: @nevada_scout, Not only for ci $this->session class, also by using $_SESSION['frontusername'], the same issue.

Comment: @devkann Is there an error being logged when you try to access the session variables? If you do `$_SESSION['frontusername'] = "test";` does it still not work?

Comment: @nevada_scout, no error. $_SESSION['frontusername'] = "test" not working

Comment: @devkann Might be a silly question, but are you sure `session_start()` is being called before you try to get/set session data?

Comment: @nevada_scout, yes, session_start() is calling, because i am able to get the session_id.

Comment: whats session permission. have you set it to 777. if not change it and try

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy, You mean for /tmp folder. Yes its 777. Inside that its having as /tmp/systemd-private-5bce9acafc2a4fafa74947e9950cefdf-apache2.service-OL9Au7. Whether the session would be written inside this?

Answer (score 0):

Check permission for session.
I had the same problem and solved it by changing permission in ami.

The local value pointing /var/lib/php/session seems to be the problem as this directory is not writable by server user. I did not know anything about local and master value, and after some digging in google I read the following:

"Master Value" (from php.ini) could be overridden with "Local Value" in httpd.conf, .htaccess or other Apache configuration with php_value directive.

So after looking around server files i found /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf which contains:

```
#
Apache specific PHP configuration options
those can be override in each configured vhost
#
php_value session.save_handler "files"
php_value session.save_path "/var/lib/php/session"
```

So there is the problem, this php.conf is overwritting default php.ini configuration. I can comment this last line wih "#" and restart the server and all is working as expected again.

Hope this help.

Comment: Which permission are you referring to? Please can you expand this answer?

Comment: ami means amazon machine image? How to change the permission for session?

Comment: Explained. Hope the answer help

Comment: Already tried this. No such path /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf or php.conf in server.

Comment: Are you sure that the session is start ai the beginning of the file with session_start()?

Comment: Yes, I am having session_start() at the top and session id is geneating.

Comment: any solution? getting the same issue